# Node JS with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, redis, hiredis

I am trying to create an authentication module to record and validate user token using  [node_redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis). However when i added it in my main Node JS api (with webpack), it gets this error during webpack bundling.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/redis-parser/lib/hiredis.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'hiredis' in '/home/username/Documents/my_backend/node_redis/node_modules/redis-parser/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/redis-parser/lib/hiredis.js 3:14-32
 @ ./node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js
 @ ./node_modules/redis-parser/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/redis/index.js
 @ ./src/redisDemo.ts
 @ ./src/server.ts
```

So after googling around i discovered that using [webpack-node-external](https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals) will able to resolve the error, by adding `externals: [nodeExternals()],` in my webpack. But by doing this way, my authentication module unable to inherit the environment variables from main node JS webpack, since we excluded authentication module from bundling in webpack.

Sorry for the long winded story, in short is there another solution to resolve `hiredis` error? without excluding my authentication module into the bundle using webpack?

Comment: Don't know your issue, but i see that in master tag, v3, there are no any more the hiredis file... Maybe should you try to update your redis-parser in using the last version...

Comment: What are the reasons you're using webpack for a nodejs app in the first place?